# Catalog Layout Not Changing

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, theme, catalog, magento-community

I am having some difficulty changing the layout of the Catalog View pages within our Enterprise installation.

The layout is currently set (somewhere) to 2-columns-left.phtml however I need to change this to 1column.phtml. I have successfully done this for a 'parent' category layout which is set in layout.xml via:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_search>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_search>
```

However when I visit the following URL: /catalog/category/view/s/a-category-name/id/46/ it is just loading `2columns-left.phtml`. My question is, how can I find out what XML file or method is setting this particular layout?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All XML files are merged before they are processed so you cannot trace back the origin easily.

But it sounds like this is a category specific update that's configured in the "Custom Design" tab:

[image: screenshot]